# Change column value alternatively based on the previous value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe I'm trying to change the column value based on the previous signal, for example if the previous signal is `BUY` then next value should be a `SELL` otherwise it should be `SKIP` same way for the `SELL` signal also.

Imaging this as stock price so after `BUY` the signal must be `SELL` that's what i'm trying to do.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Price':[3.4, 3.5, 3.2, 3.3, 3.2, 3.7, 4, 3.1, 3.4, 3.1],
        'Signal':['BUY', 'SELL', np.nan, 'BUY', 'BUY', 'SELL', np.nan, 'SELL', 'SELL', 'BUY']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

output

```
0   3.4 BUY
1   3.5 SELL
2   3.2 NaN
3   3.3 BUY
4   3.2 BUY
5   3.7 SELL
6   4.0 NaN
7   3.1 SELL
8   3.4 SELL
9   3.1 BUY
```

I'm expecting an output like the following.

```
0   3.4 BUY
1   3.5 SELL
2   3.2 SKIP
3   3.3 BUY
4   3.2 SKIP
5   3.7 SELL
6   4.0 SKIP
7   3.1 SKIP
8   3.4 SKIP
9   3.1 BUY
```

I tried the following code but it didn't work as expected.

`df.Signal = df.Signal.mask(df.Signal.shift(1) == df.Signal, 'SKIP')`

How I can make it alternative `BUY` and `SELL` signal and everything else as `SKIP`?

Comment: Somebody downvoted this may I know why?

Comment: I didn't downvote but the question is unclear. The dataframe produced from your `data` sample does not contain any NaNs, but there are NaN values in the example? How you want the signals to alternate is also unclear.

Comment: @gereleth - Sorry for that, I updated the code. I adde that NaN later but forgot to update in question.

Comment: there are some border cases you need to address, e.g. what should be produced on sequences like `BUY, None, SELL` and `BUY, None, BUY`, multiple NaNs etc.

Comment: @Marat - It must alternate `BUY` and `SELL` everything else should be `SKIP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably work

```
s = df.Signal.fillna(method='ffill')
df.loc[s==s.shift(),'Signal'] = 'SKIP'
```